# Проблема со Sprite и его физикой

Tags: c#, unity3d

Почему Sprite имеющий BoxCollider2D и Rigidbody2D, при изменении гравитации немного проваливается под Ground, но потом встает нормально на него?

[Видео что происходит](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/5gm5/2cH2cYBRU)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вопрос слишком общий. Гравитация нейтивная или ты сам реализовал? Какие настройки у ригитбоди? Какие коллайдеры? Прикрепить видео или гифку с примером?

Comment: Я прикрепил скрин настроек Игрока, видео прикреплю позже.

Comment: Не очень правильное решение(скорее хак), но может сработать. Измени колижн детекшн на любой другой и перепроверь.

Comment: Я прикрепил видео, но еще не пробовал ваш "хак".

Comment: Просто суть в том что слева от блока есть тригер на смерть, а по блоку я должен перемещаться.

Comment: Все сработало спасибо большое!